# Size overhead of Flite TTS engine

Tags: ios, flite

I want to integrate Flite TTS into my iOS app. The Flite download is close to 68 MB. The source files added to the project occupy a lot of size. I want to know the extra overhead of using Flite TTS library in my iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flite overhead is about 3 MB for a single voice and can go upto 15 MB for multiple voices. The quality of voice is also not that great for the default 3 MB voice.